# Need to change focus to another text box before buttons are activated

Tags: selenium, click

I am entering data into text fields in a browser via "type" command.  In order for the `Save` and `Cancel` buttons to be activated (not grayed out), I need to click in another text field to change focus.  This works manually, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it programmatically.  I have tried click, `clickAt, doubleClick, mouseOver/click/mouseOUt, mouseDown/mouseUp, focus, fireEvent` ... all without luck.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Where you are trying to give focus after clicking the second text field? Please provide the code you tried.

Answer (score 11):

Does tabbing out of the input field enable the buttons? If so, maybe you can just do:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("your_input_field"));
element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```